# webpack error -ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs Unexpected token: name (urlParts)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, node-modules, babeljs

I am starting to learn webpack. I created a simple config file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  publicPath: '/',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
},
devtool: 'inline-source-map',
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  hot: true
},
plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      use: ['babel-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
      use: ['file-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
      use: ['file-loader']
    }
   ] 
 }
};
```

Then I created src/index.js with a simple console.log('hello').

In package.json I put this: 
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.local.js -p",

When I run "npm start" in the terminal I get this weird error:

ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (urlParts) [(webpack)-dev-server/client?http:/localhost:8080:24,0][bundle.js:4026,4]

The bundle.js looks very weird since I haven't write all this code. I googled but cannot find the solution, do you have any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Edit: I added this in .babelrc but still same error:

```
{"presets": ["react", "stage-2", "es2015"]}
```

Comment: Are you using `UglifyJS`? What version of webpack are you running?

Comment: "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.8.2", I am not using uglify. This error is driving me crazy and I cannot find a solution. It says that I have 4000 lines of code in the bundle while In my index I only put a console.log

Comment: `"start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.local.js -p"`
Have you tried changing that line to: `"start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.local.js"`?

Comment: Webpack is building for production which is what `-p` flag means. From Webpack v2+ UglifyJS is built into them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the -p from your npm script, this is why is minifying the code.
It seems that you are using webpack-dev-server and a config.local file so I assume this is only for local development, in this case the -p from webpack it's not needed.

Regarding the size of bundle.js I see you are excluding the node_modules folder, so it seems ok for me. Try to add a new script in your package.json like this:

```
"build": ""webpack --config webpack.config.local.js"
```

and see the file that will be created, so you can better understand what is going on. 
Hope this help, cheers!

Comment: Yep that fixed the issue, without -p it does not minify the code, thanks